# Bind9 Change Default Config Location

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, bind, docker

I'm aware that bind has an option to change the default config location, and can be applied in /etc/default/bind9.

```
# run resolvconf?
RESOLVCONF=no

# startup options for the server
OPTIONS="-f -4 -u bind -c /etc/newDir/named.conf"
```

I changed the named of the default named.conf file to show that it is still trying to load the default config file:

```
Oct 06 12:24:09 ubuntu named[2129]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf' Oct 06 12:24:09 ubuntu named[2129]: open: /etc/bind/named.conf: file not found Oct 06 12:24:09 ubuntu named[2129]: loading configuration: file not found Oct 06 12:24:09 ubuntu named[2129]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

However when I restart bind, the new config location is not loaded, the original file is used. Is there a better way to set the location? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!